# Attempt to index local 'v' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, indexing, null

I'm trying to edit a lua script to add on my Garry's Mod Server, but I get this error and I dont know what to do.

Error:

> [ERROR] --/sh_worlditemspawner.lua:56: attempt to index local 'v' (a nil value)

Code:

```
local PLUGIN = PLUGIN
PLUGIN.name = "World Item Spawner"
PLUGIN.author = "Black Tea"
PLUGIN.desc = "World Item Spawner."
PLUGIN.itempoints = PLUGIN.itempoints or {}
PLUGIN.spawngroups = { 
    ["default"] = {
        {"bleach"},
    },
    ["example"] = {
        {"ration"},
    },
    ["junks"] = { 
        {"junk_ws"},
        {"junk_wj"},
        {"junk_be"},
        {"junk_bt"},
        {"junk_p"},
        {"junk_ss"},
        {"junk_bl"},
        {"junk_k"},
        {"junk_p"},
        {"junk_hp"},
        {"junk_ec"},
        {"junk_ej"},
    }
}

PLUGIN.spawnrate = 30
PLUGIN.maxitems = 10
PLUGIN.itemsperspawn = 2
PLUGIN.spawneditems = PLUGIN.spawneditems or {}

if SERVER then
    local spawntime = 1
    function PLUGIN:Think()
        if spawntime > CurTime() then return end
        spawntime = CurTime() + self.spawnrate
        for k, v in ipairs(self.spawneditems) do
            if (!v:IsValid()) then
                table.remove(self.spawneditems, k)
            end
        end

        if #self.spawneditems >= self.maxitems then return end

        for i = 1, self.itemsperspawn do
            if #self.spawneditems >= self.maxitems then return end
            local v = table.Random(self.itempoints)
            if #self.spawneditems > self.maxitems then
                return
            end


            local data = {}
            data.start = v[1]
            data.endpos = data.start + Vector(0, 0, 1)
            data.filter = client
            data.mins = Vector(-16, -16, 0)
            data.maxs = Vector(16, 16, 16)
            local trace = util.TraceHull(data)

            if trace.Entity:IsValid() then
                continue
            end

            local idat = table.Random(self.spawngroups[v[2]]) or self.spawngroup["default"]
            local item = nut.item.Spawn(v[1] + Vector( math.Rand(-8,8), math.Rand(-8,8), 10 ), AngleRand(), idat[1], idat[2] or {})
            table.insert( self.spawneditems, item )
        end
    end

    function PLUGIN:LoadData()
        self.itempoints = nut.util.ReadTable("itempoints")
    end

    function PLUGIN:SaveData()
        for k, v in ipairs(self.spawneditems) do
            v:Remove()
        end
        nut.util.WriteTable("itempoints", self.itempoints)
    end
else
    netstream.Hook("nut_DisplaySpawnPoints", function(data)
        for k, v in pairs(data) do
            local emitter = ParticleEmitter( v[1] )
            local smoke = emitter:Add( "sprites/glow04_noz", v[1] )
            smoke:SetVelocity( Vector( 0, 0, 1 ) )
            smoke:SetDieTime(10)
            smoke:SetStartAlpha(255)
            smoke:SetEndAlpha(255)
            smoke:SetStartSize(64)
            smoke:SetEndSize(64)
            smoke:SetColor(255,186,50)
            smoke:SetAirResistance(300)
            emitter:Finish()
        end
    end)
end

nut.command.Register({
    adminOnly = true,
    onRun = function(client, arguments)
        local trace = client:GetEyeTraceNoCursor()
        local hitpos = trace.HitPos + trace.HitNormal*5
        local spawngroup = arguments[1] or "default"
        table.insert( PLUGIN.itempoints, { hitpos, spawngroup } )
        nut.util.Notify( "You added ".. spawngroup .. " item spawner." )
    end
}, "itemspawnadd")

nut.command.Register({
    adminOnly = true,
    onRun = function(client, arguments)
        local trace = client:GetEyeTraceNoCursor()
        local hitpos = trace.HitPos + trace.HitNormal*5
        local range = arguments[1] or 128
        local mt = 0
        for k, v in pairs( PLUGIN.itempoints ) do
            local distance = v[1]:Distance( hitpos )
            if distance <= tonumber(range) then
                PLUGIN.itempoints[k] = nil
                mt = mt + 1
            end
        end
        nut.util.Notify( mt .. " item spawners has been removed.")
    end
}, "itemspawnremove")

nut.command.Register({
    adminOnly = true,
    onRun = function(client, arguments)
        if SERVER then
            netstream.Start(client, "nut_DisplaySpawnPoints", PLUGIN.itempoints)
            nut.util.Notify( "Displayed All Points for 10 secs." )
        end
    end
}, "itemspawndisplay")
```

Comment: Should add in a few of the things you have tried to fix this issue, or reference what you are attempting to do so that others can lead you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

This is because

```
table.Random(self.itempoints)
```

returns nil. Did you mean math.random?  If you post code for that table.Random func I can give more info.